# AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 04) does not work on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, audio, drivers

i have intalled ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer Aspire 1690 wich has sound driver

> Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW
> (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 04)

the problem that this doesn't sound. Alsamixer says:

> card: Intel ICH6
>
> chip: Conexant Cx20468-31

The master, headphone, PCM and line volumen are on. Also try to use a usb audio card and neither it work.